# Error when installing Diamondback on Ubuntu

Tags: ros-diamondback

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Dear all,
I follow the step in http://www.ros.org/wiki/diamondback/Installation/Ubuntu

When I want to **Set up my keys**, there is an error: " gpg: can't find available OpenPGP data " .

And the following steps can't work.

How can I solve the problem? Thanks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/12101/error-when-installing-diamondback-on-ubuntu/) by [Ting](https://answers.ros.org/users/1445/ting/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2011-11-25

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

That's the error you get if your download fails.  I'd suggest you try again.  If it doesn't work please edit your question to include your console output.

Using an invalid url I get that errors:

```
wget http://packages.ros.org/ros.keyinvalid -O - | sudo apt-key add - 
--2011-11-26 12:48:22--  http://packages.ros.org/ros.keyinvalid
Resolving packages.ros.org... 157.22.19.137
Connecting to packages.ros.org|157.22.19.137|:80... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 404 Not Found
2011-11-26 12:48:22 ERROR 404: Not Found.
gpg: no valid OpenPGP data found.
```

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2011-11-26

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1